# How to describe an individual who always speaks in a "matter of fact" manner

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives, idiom-requests, epithet-requests

I have a friend who always speaks in a very matter-of-fact manner.  On numerous occasions, he has mentioned how it was "the best BLANK" he has ever had, or "the best BLANK in the city."

Everything he speaks of is absolute in a overly self-assured manner (almost to a fault, since he is not always correct or has contradicted himself because of previous statements...how many bars in the city can have the best cocktail?).  But on the other hand, he is very convincing/charismatic so it is easy to get swept away by his passion.

Anyway...are there any good idioms, or single words that might sum up this type of individual?

The following adjectives are the best ones I could come up with to describe this type of person: "very matter-of-fact" and "absolute" (but to a fault) but since he is so "self-assured", "charismatic" and "convincing" it's hard to see through this.

Comment: It sounds like this fellow is the **opposite** of matter-of-fact.

Comment: @Oldcat "matter-of-falsehood"?

Comment: exaggerator - hyperbolist - fond of embroidering - a convincing Munchausen ...

Comment: **BS Artist**? Hahaha! Just kidding. How about `pseudo-authoritative`? ;-)

Comment: I know exactly what your saying. Its hard to put into words. Im pretty sure Im the same personality type,as your buddy. I speak everything in a matter of fact way cause Im so worried about not having any credibility. However if its something Im super excited about or passionate about I will partake in what some would call Hyoerbole however at the time Im saying it I absolutley believe my proclamation. For example if I say this is the best orange Ive ate in my life.
At the time I saying it I absolutley believe it. Hard to put my thoughts and feelings to words.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you think your friend is a **know-it-all**.

He might think of himself as **authoritative**, a **connoisseur**, or a **maven**.

But given your example I would also offer, a **Pollyanna**.

> an excessively cheerful or optimistic person.
>
> A Pollyanna would be the opposite of someone who is critical.  Their
>   advice would be just as bad because to them everything that they know
>   is the "best".

Comment: Also: @RyeɃreḁd ... And, yes I'm aware of the hypocrisy in that statement.  ;-)

Comment: @DavidM - I am going to cry and make a meta-question based on the insensitivity of the ELU members.

Comment: Yes ... And, I will be forced to carry on a prolonged comments war with you over it, too.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ryebread's answers.

**Full of shit**.

**A bullshit artist**.

**A blowhard**.

All of these are pejoratives for that type of person.  The first two can carry the connotation of him being exceptionally convincing.  (Full of shit is not always used in this way, but it is on occasion.)

Less pejorative:

**Smooth-talking**

**Slick**

Again, I've selected these on the basis of being very convincing without there needing to be actual veracity in his statements.

How do I know these terms?  I get called all of them on a daily basis.  *It takes one to know one!*

Answer (score 0):

he's infectiously (or contagiously) affirmative

other options: a booster, promoter, endorser or enthusiast

Such a term could be preceded by "unpaid" or "self-appointed" or followed by "by avocation."